# How to Use FindPlane()

Tags: google-project-tango

Could someone explain to me how FindPlane works? (I understand the inputs, and the outputs, but not the process.) I am getting random values for the output and therefore I do not understand how it actually functions: does it raycast a normal vector from my camera according to my touch position and gets the depth point that hit the raycast and gets a plane out of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operation is similar to raycast, but other way round. When you click any point on screen, screen coordinates are recorded. All 3D points in Pointcloud are projected onto image plane using camera intrinsic. Points which are close to screen coordinates are taken. **RANSAC** method is used to extract plane information from those points. **SVD** can also be used to extract plane normal from inliers obtained from RANSAC. This method should be used only once per frame transformation operation is applied on all points in pointcloud.

This method gives random values in cases where Sparse Pointcloud, reflections in 3D point cloud, reflective surfaces, Cluttered 3D space, IR from outside etc.,